# Looking for a GUI automation framework that works with .NET (WinForms)

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation

Currently we're using AutoIT for automating a few internal tools built with WinForms.

This is not a smooth process since AutoIT does not handle .NET windows very well as far as I could see.

I'm looking for a framework that is:

1. Free (or very cheap).
2. Works with WinForms/WPF and any other .NET technology.
   By this I mean robust control identification that will redue overhead of maintaining the
   project with every small UI change of the application.
3. No scripting/minimal scripting involved (if possible - in a popular language).
4. Record mode to record runs.

Comment: I'd like to also add to the question -- is there any specific process in WinForms development that should make the automated ui testing easier?

Comment: Here's a library for AutoIt that lets you deal with .NET windows very well: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/79449-identify-net-controls-by-their-name/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [White](http://white.codeplex.com/).
From the site:

> White is a framework for automating
>   rich client applications based on
>   Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and
>   SWT (Java) platforms. It is .NET based
>   and does not require the use of any
>   proprietary scripting languages.
>   Tests/automation programs using White
>   can be written with whatever .NET
>   language, IDE and tools you are
>   already using. White provides a
>   consistent object-oriented API, hiding
>   the complexity of Microsoft's
>   UIAutomation library (on which White
>   is based) and windows messages. Only
>   stable versions of White are released,
>   so all releases are production-ready.

Comment: I downloaded it and will try using it now. It looks like it's been some time since it was last updated. Anyone knows if its still under active development? (maybe in some other site)

Answer (score 2):

Posting explicit AutoIt code from the comments...

```
#include <DotNetIdentification.au3>

; "Test App" is a fake application with a control named "txtShowMe". 
$WindowName = "Test App"
$WindowText = ""

$control = NET_ControlGetHandleByName( $WindowName, $WindowText, "txtShowMe" )
if @error = 0 then 
    WinActivate( $WindowName, $WindowText )
    ControlFocus( $WindowName, $WindowText, $control )
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your are looking to test automate .NET apps then presmably your are working in a .NET development house. If thats the case there is a good chance yor have an **MSDN subscription**. If you do AND if its at the **Premium** (or better) level then you can author UI automation tests using the *Coded UI Test type within a Visual Studio test project*.

- This is free ASSUMING your already have an **MSDN** subscription at
  **Premium** or above
- It tests WinForms, WPF and ASP.NET UI.
- Its not as fully featured as a dedicated UI automation toolkit, but you may
  already own it!
- Can author tests by recording the UX test run
- If you have to change/customzie tests its no so much scripted but full bown .NET you get to edit; maximum power, but if you dont code .NET already also maximum learning curve